# MATLAB Neural Network - Forward Propagation

Tags: matlab, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am creating a Forward Propagation In the feedforward step, an input pattern is propagated through the network to obtain an output. I have written this in pseudo code and currently attempting to implement this within MATLAB.

There are two errors I currently receive.

```
Patterns = x'; Desired = y; NHIDDENS = 1; prnout=Desired;
% Patterns become x so number of inputs becomes size of patterns

[NINPUTS,NPATS] = size(Patterns); [NOUTPUTS,NP] = size(Desired);
%apply the backprop here...

LearnRate = 0.15; Momentum = 0; DerivIncr = 0; deltaW1 = 0; deltaW2 = 0;
% Keeps the tan ordering of the examples of x
Inputs1= [Patterns;ones(1,NPATS)]; %Inputs1 = [ones(1,NPATS); Patterns];
% Weight initialisation
Weights1 = 0.5*(rand(NHIDDENS,1+NINPUTS)-0.5);
Weights2 = 0.5*(rand(1,1+NHIDDENS)-0.5); 
TSS_Limit = 0.02;

for epoch = 1:10
    
%     FORWARD LOOP 

size(NOUTPUTS)
size(NPATS)
    for ii = 0: ii < length(NINPUTS)
        NOUTPUTS(ii+1) = NPATS(ii);
%         Sets bias to 1
        NOUTPUTS(1) = 1;
    end
    for ii = NHIDDENS: ii < NINPUTS 
        sum = 0;
        for ij = 0: ij < ii
            sum = sum + deltaW1(ii,ij) * NOUTPUTS(ij);
            NOUTPUTS(ii) = tanh(sum);
        end
            
    end
```

```
Unable to perform assignment because the
left and right sides have a different
number of elements.

Error in mlpts (line 66)
        NOUTPUTS(i+1) = NPATS(i);
```

i am still new to MATLAB and trying to become use to it.

After iterating through the loop
NOUTPUTS = 0 and the error is displayed. I am confused as I am trying to increment NOUTPUTS with ii by 1 through each loop.

Comment: _"Array indices must be **positive** integers or
logical values."_ In `NOUTPUTS(0)`, `0` is not a positive integer. Matlab array indices are 1-based

Comment: MATLAB indices start at 1, not 0

Comment: would putting NOUTPUTS(1) allow me to access the first element within the array?

Comment: @EricaSantos yes, it would be the index of the first element

Comment: What do you get from `size(NOUTPUTS)` and `size(NPATS)`?

Comment: I wanted to check if they had the same sizes which they do, hence why I don't understand why I receive the error of "Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements." @PranavHosangadi

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and monitor the values of `ii`, `NOUTPUTS(ii)` and `NPATS(ii)`? Or print those in the loop before `NOUTPUTS(ii) = NPATS(ii)` so you'll be able to check what's actually happening? It's weird, you shouldn't be getting that error if the sizes are identical.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - The output for NOUTPUTS(ii) = 1 ; The output for ii = 1 ; The output for NPATS(ii) = 10

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - After iterating through the loop NOUTPUTS = 0 and the error is displayed. I am confused as I am trying to increment NOUTPUTS with ii by 1 through each loop.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi any advice?

Comment: We don't have enough debugging information to answer your question. The bounty is not going to help. But it seems you have some fundamental logic errors in your loops. I would suggest stepping through the loops with the debugger to verify that your code is doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create the forward propagation with a loop.

```
    for i =3:NNODES
      summ = 0;
      for j=1:i-1
          summ = summ + weights(i,j) * Node_outputs(j);
      end
      if i == NNODES
          Node_outputs(i) = summ
      else
          Node_outputs(i) = sigmoid(summ);
      end
  end
  Out = Node_outputs(NNODES);
%   BOut = ((Node_outputs(NNODES)) * (1 - Node_outputs));
  BOut=zeros(1,6);
  DeltaWeight = zeros(6,6);
```